# Yii accessing a nested module

Tags: yii, rights

I have an admin module which I'm using for backend user management etc...

I would like to have the 'rights' extension nested under this admin module and be able to get to it with `mysite.com/index.php?r=admin/rights`

Apparently I need to declare child modules in the parent so under the AdminModule init, i've set:

```
$this->setModules(array(
    'rights'=>array(
        'install'=>true, // rights - Enables the installer
        'baseUrl'=>'/admin/rights',
        'debug'=>true,
    ),
));
```

I've also tried importing from AdminModule init: (clueless on this one)

```
$this->setImport(array(
    'admin.models.*',
    'admin.components.*',
    'admin.modules.rights.*',
    'admin.modules.rights.components.*',
));
```

Also I've tried declaring the module in the main.php config:

```
'admin'=>array(
    'modules'=>array(
        'rights'=>array(
            'install'=>true, // rights - Enables the installer
            'baseUrl'=>'/admin/rights',
            'debug'=>true,
         ),
     ),
),
```

And even importing it there:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.modules.admin.*',
    'application.modules.admin.modules.rights.*', // rights
    'application.modules.admin.modules.rights.components.*', // rights
),
```

Anywho, no matter what I've tried so far, I cannot get to the rights module. It gives me `Unable to resolve the request "admin/rights".` when trying to get to admin/rights.

The extension works fine as an un-nested module at `?r=rights`. Any ideas? I've not found many examples of the actual code when dealing with nested modules.

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be a missing route?

Try adding the following:

```
<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>
```

Comment: Nope, no luck. I enabled clean urls and added that route but still am getting the 404

Comment: actually, would that go in the main.php or the AdminModule.php?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have multiple `rights` modules. To use particular one (from „deeper“ hierarchy) you must declare its class. Something like that:

```
'admin'=>array(
    'modules'=>array(
        'rights'=>array(
            'class' => 'application.modules.admin.modules.rights.RightsModule'
         ),
     ),
),
```